# OleDB in Pythonnet and Mono on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, mono, oledb, python.net

I am trying to run several method of a dll library that I own. I use pythonnet 3.0.0dev, python3.9 and Mono 6.10.0. One of the methods triggers creating an .mdb file. On a windows machine I've install Microsoft Access Database Engine (suggested by the dll provider) and I could run my script without any problem. However, doing the same on a Mac OS X triggers the following error:

```
NotImplementedException: OleDb is not implemented.
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection..ctor () [0x0000b] in <bd12f551d3b343c5a146c906291931e8>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection..ctor()
  at Csu.Modsim.NetworkUtils.DBUtil.OpenDBConnection () [0x0000b] in <1c83b754d09149ce95a722be79ca7efb>:0 
  at Csu.Modsim.NetworkUtils.DBUtil.Create (System.Boolean Overwrite, System.Boolean LeaveOpen) [0x00026] in <1c83b754d09149ce95a722be79ca7efb>:0 
  at Csu.Modsim.NetworkUtils.ModelOutputMSDB.InitializeOutput () [0x000a6] in <1c83b754d09149ce95a722be79ca7efb>:0 
  at Csu.Modsim.NetworkUtils.ModelOutputSupport.FlushOutputToCSV (Csu.Modsim.ModsimModel.Model mi, System.Boolean finalizeOutput) [0x0030d] in <1c83b754d09149ce95a722be79ca7efb>:0 
  at Csu.Modsim.ModsimModel.GlobalMembersOperate.operate (Csu.Modsim.ModsimModel.Model mi, Csu.Modsim.ModsimModel.Model mi2) [0x012ab] in <6f164bf9bd4744b9a0c1e4daaabc0e8a>:0 
  at Csu.Modsim.ModsimModel.Modsim.RunSolver (Csu.Modsim.ModsimModel.Model mi) [0x002f7] in <6f164bf9bd4744b9a0c1e4daaabc0e8a>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in <55adae4546cd485ba70e2948332ebe8c>:0
```

What could be a possible solution to this problem. All my installed components are 64-bit.

Thanks

Comment: http://modsim.engr.colostate.edu/contactus.shtml You probably should write to the authors to see if they even support Mono and macOS. If they only support Windows, you have to stick to Windows.

Comment: Of course, however, this part seems to be separate from the software itself and more related to the Microsoft Access?